# Intent issue in from activity to navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="associate.aclass.associate1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".registration"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

registration.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.registration);

                //initializing firebase auth object
                firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                //initializing views
                editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
                editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

                buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

                //attaching listener to button
                buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            private void registerUser(){

                //getting email and password from edit texts
                String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                //checking if email and passwords are empty
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                //if the email and password are not empty
                //displaying a progress dialog

                progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
                progressDialog.show();

                //creating a new user
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                //checking if success
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    //display some message here
                                    Toast.makeText(registration.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Intent i=new Intent(registration.this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
                                }else{
                                    //display some message here
                                    Toast.makeText(registration.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //calling register method on click
                registerUser();
            }
        }
```

in my MainActivity.java
    There is navigation drawer template provided by android studio

**Issue is:**
When i intent from registration to other activity like abc.class. Its working fine but when i intent from registration to MainActivity.class that contains navigration drawer. My Application crashed after click on sign up. registration process done then my application crashed. Instead of crash, it should show navigration drawer

Comment: Please add your crashreport/stacktrace.

Comment: Which exception you are getting? and if you are using a toolbar in your main activity and setting that to get action bar property. So add a line in your manifesto that in <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> </activity>

Comment: @RobinVinzenz issue has been resolved .. i didn't add the android:theme

Comment: @kishansahu Thanks mate.. you made my day

Comment: So @RobinVinzenz  vote my comment and welcome buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a toolbar in your main activity and setting that to get action bar property. So add a line in your manifesto that in

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>
```

I hope it will solve your problem..